# tso ispf "view save termination" how to change the default

Tags: mainframe, tso, ispf

When exiting from TSO View, the "View Termination" window is displayed with the default "N" (Not to save).
How can I change the default to "Y" (Yes to save)?

Answer (score 4):

You can't - the whole point of 'View' (as opposed to 'Edit'), is that it doesn't save - i.e. you have all the editing tools, macros etc but you can safely hit PF3 knowing you won't change the data.

If you want to edit it, use 'Edit'. If you change your mind whilst using View and decide you'd like to keep your data, use the 'create' or 'replace' line commands. I use '`create .zf .zl`' or '`replace .zf .zl`' to save all data (i.e. from the first line (.zf) to the last line (.zl)).

Alternatively, you might be using the ISPF Workplace (and if you are not, you should as it's very good). Here. when you enter a dataset name with nothing in the 'Action' field, the default action is to invoke View, which is why you're wondering how to get into Edit. You can override this action by specifying 'e' in the Action field and you will then be taken in to Edit.

'v' (for view) in this case is the 'Default Enter Action' and can be changed (so, for example, that pressing enter with no action will take you into Edit) by using the pull down menus - Options -> Workplace Settings -> Defaults -> Default Enter Action. I use 'Smart Action', which attempts the most logical action, depending upon they type of object (PDS, sequential dataset, dataset mask etc).